# simplify 1 + (BC) logic gate

Tags: logic-gates, boolean-algebra, karnaugh-map

Can someone please confirm that 1 + BC = 1. I have to simplify function 
A' + ABC to get A' + BC.

Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes I can confirm it. Also it is obvious if you think that A' + ABC = A' + BC. If A = 0 then the first term (A') is true, so the whole expression is true. Only if A=1 is it important what the second term is, in this case only B and C are variables, as A=1 by definition.

Comment: Thank you sir, I now understand thanks to your explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, 1 OR anything = 1, so 1 + BC = 1.